# Executing Multiple SQL statements using execute()

Tags: python, sql, mariadb, sql-injection, stacked-query

I am trying to do an `SQL injection` in a server of mine.
I am using the command :

```
cursor.execute("select * from some_table")
```

to execute the SQL commands in my server.
But is there a way to execute multiple commands using the same `execute()` function.
I tried :

```
cursor.execute("select * from some_table ; INSERT INTO ...")
```

DBMS is `mariadb`

Comment: No, it only allows executing one statement at a time.

Comment: Just call `cursor.execute()` multiple times.

Comment: You can look into `executemany`, which for example can be used to insert multiple rows of data in one call more efficiently than multiple calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/sql-injection-cheat-sheet/#StackingQueries) is an overview of SQL injection strategies. The one you are trying to do is called *stacking queries*. It seems that at least this strategy is prevented by most database APIs.

You mention MariaDB which is basically more or less the same as MySQL.

And although python is not listed explicitly, I would also assume that the python database API prevents query stacking.

**Update:** When you check the API of `execute()` you can see there is a parameter `multi` which defaults to `False`. As long as you don't set it to `True`, you should be safe.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL (and MariaDB) allows you to run several SQL statements in one go by setting [capability flag](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/capability-flags.html)  `CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS` (0x10000) on connecting to the database server. Check out the documentation of the python database driver used in your implementation, there should be method to set the flag and you need to do so in advance before creating cursor and execute the SQL statements.

Here is the code example of `mariadb` python driver, for other drivers (like `pymysql`) they may work the same way

```py
import mariadb
from mariadb.constants.CLIENT import MULTI_STATEMENTS

conn_params= {
    "user" : "YOUR_USERNAME",
    "password" : "YOUR_PASSWORD",
    "host" : "NETWORK_DOMAIN_NAME",
    "database" : "DB_NAME",
    "client_flag": MULTI_STATEMENTS,
}

db_conn = mariadb.connect(**conn_params)

rawsqls = [
    'SELECT * FROM table2',
    'INSERT INTO table3 ....',
    'SELECT * FROM table4',
]

with db_conn.cursor() as cursor:
     cursor.execute(';'.join(rawsqls))
     rows1 = cursor.fetchall()
     cursor.nextset()
     rows2 = cursor.fetchall()
     cursor.nextset()
     rows3 = cursor.fetchall()
```

**CAUTION**

To avoid SQL injection, You should be careful and use the flag `CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS` ONLY when you are pretty sure that all the inputs to your SQL statements come from trusted source.